# Optimizing and Accelerating File Upload Speed to Google Drive in PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Google Drive to upload images, videos, etc. However, I find its performance quite slow, even though I've implemented chunking. Is there any optimization method to boost the upload speed? Or are there any CDNs similar to Google Drive but with faster speeds? Please help me address this issue. Thank you :<

```
 public static function uploadFile($file)
{
    $client = self::getClient();
    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Check if 'social' folder exists
    $socialFolderId = self::checkFolderExists($driveService, 'social');

    // If 'social' folder doesn't exist, create it
    if (!$socialFolderId) {
        $folderMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
            'name' => 'social',
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        ]);
        $createdFolder = $driveService->files->create($folderMetadata, [
            'fields' => 'id',
        ]);
        $socialFolderId = $createdFolder->id;
    }

    // Create a folder name based on the date
    $dateFolderName = date('d-m-Y');
    $dateFolderExists = self::checkFolderExists($driveService, $dateFolderName);

    // If the date folder doesn't exist, create it in the 'social' folder
    if (!$dateFolderExists) {
        $folderMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
            'name' => $dateFolderName,
            'parents' => [$socialFolderId],
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        ]);
        $createdFolder = $driveService->files->create($folderMetadata, [
            'fields' => 'id',
        ]);
        $folderId = $createdFolder->id;
    } else {
        // If the date folder exists, use its id
        $folderId = $dateFolderExists;
    }

    // Generate a new file name
    $newFileName = bin2hex(random_bytes(16)) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Define allowed extensions
    $allowedExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'exe', 'vtt', 'mp4', 'txt', 'zip', 'rar', 'docx', 'pdf', 'msi'];
    $fileExtension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedExtensions)) {
        // Define the chunk size
        $chunkSizeBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB

        // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // File metadata
        $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
            'name' => $newFileName,
            'parents' => [$folderId],
        ]);

        // Create a request
        $request = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata);

        // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
        $media = new \Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $request,
            'application/octet-stream',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );

        // Set file size
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($file->getRealPath()));

        // Upload the various chunks.
        // The status will be false until the process is complete.
        $status = false;

        // Open file handle
        $handle = fopen($file->getRealPath(), "rb");
        $totalFileSize = filesize($file->getRealPath());
        $uploadedSize = 0;

        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
            // Read a chunk of file
            $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);

            // Upload the chunk
            $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            $uploadedSize += strlen($chunk);

            // Calculate the progress based on the uploaded size
            $progress = ($uploadedSize / $totalFileSize) * 100;

            // Send an event with the current progress
            event(new FileUploadProgressEvent($progress));
        }

        // Ensure the final progress is sent, even if it doesn't reach 100%
        if ($progress < 100) {
            event(new FileUploadProgressEvent(100));
        }

        // Close file handle
        fclose($handle);

        // Reset to the client to execute requests immediately in the future.
        $client->setDefer(false);
        // Create permissions for the file
        $permissionMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
            'type' => 'anyone',
            'role' => 'reader',
        ]);

        // Add permissions to the file
        $driveService->permissions->create($status->id, $permissionMetadata);

        // Get file metadata
        $uploadedFile = $driveService->files->get($status->id, ['fields' => 'webViewLink']);
        $downloadLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" . $status->id;
        // return ['downloadLink' => $downloadLink, 'webViewLink' => $uploadedFile->webViewLink, 'id' => $status->id];
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'File uploaded successfully!',
            'filename' => $newFileName,
            'filepath' => $downloadLink,
            'fileId' => $status->id
        ]);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can speed this up, but any reader of your question would get a much better idea of what you mean if you quantify "quite slow" and "faster speeds". Are we talking about 10Kb/s to 100 Kb/s?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your showing script, is this issue tracker related to your question? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220523936

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package (masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext) to use google drive like a Storage disk in Laravel. This package is very easy to use. I don’t know if this package can speed up the upload but the code will be more clear and efficient.